# Stemming of words using python

Tags: python, shell

I have 2 files; **root_words.txt** and **affix_words.txt**. What's I would like to do is matching the root words in affix_words.txt and replace the root word in affix_words.txt to "I" character and before root words replace with "E" character and after root words replace with "B".

For example:

```
read
xxxx
```

root_words.txt

```
reading
aaaxxxxyyy
```

affix_words.txt

output that I want is:

```
r e a d i n g<TAB>I I I I B I I
a a a x x x x y y y<TAB>I I E I I I I B I I
```

I try to match the root_words.txt with affix_words.txt by using Linux command:

```
fgrep -f "root_words.txt" "affix_words.txt"
```

but how to replace root words with "I" character

Comment: Didn't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: OP must mean, "please write this for me" because I don't see any effort.

Comment: I would like to stemming the words that mix with affixes. The first thing that I need to do is identify the root words first. Thus I decided to make 2 files. First file is list all root words and second file is the words that mix with affixes. For example: reading (the root word of reading is "read"). The output that I want is root word will be replaced with "I" character and after root word will be replace with "B" character.  "r e a d i n g      I I I I B I I"

Comment: So if your root word is `efghijk` and the affix word is `abcdefghijklmn`, you want an output line of `a b c d e f g h i j k l m n\tI I I E I I I I I I I B I I`, right? Also are the words case-sensitive? And are they in the correct order (line 1 in root file corresponds to line 1 in affix file)?

Comment: @ByteCommander yes, that is what I would. No words case-sensitive and they already in correct order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this simple approach:

```
with open "root_words.txt" as rfile, "affix_words.txt" as afile:
    try:
        rw_start = aword.index(rword)
        rw_end = rw_start + len(rword)
        result = " ".join( "E" if n==rw_start-1 else \
                           "B" if n==rw_end else \
                           "I" for (n, letter) in enumerate(aword) )
    except:
        result = "NOT FOUND!"
    print("root: '{}', affixed: '{}', stemmed: '{}'".format(rword, aword, result))
```

**Example:**

`root_words.txt`:

```
read
vote
like
```

`affix_words.txt`:

```
reading
upvote
unlikely
```

Output:

```
root: 'read', affixed: 'reading', stemmed: 'I I I I B I I'
root: 'vote', affixed: 'upvote', stemmed: 'I E I I I I'
root: 'like', affixed: 'unlikely', stemmed: 'I E I I I I B I'
```

[See this code running on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/lWWhed)

Comment: Thanks for your solution

Comment: Instead of writing "thank you"-comments, please accept the answer by clicking the grey check button on the left of it if it solved your problem@YoePass.

Comment: I'm appreciate your solution but I was found the other solution. Thanks again

Comment: @YoePass You asked for a Python solution and I wrote one for you. Why are you suddenly preferring AWK???

Comment: I'm sorry and appreciate you @Byte Commander. I asked for shell script and already mentioned  in my question.

Comment: @YoePass The initial version of your question was tagged with [tag:python]. And AWK is not a shell script either btw.

Comment: Ok, I will add python as this solution and a bit change question. Thank you so much. Is it AWK is scripting?. I'm still confusing and sorry again. I'm really a newbie

Comment: AWK is a separate scripting language. It's preinstalled in most environments where you normally use shells scripts, but it is a separate tool that interprets its own language. A real shell scripting language would be e.g. Bash.

Comment: @ByteCommander Let it go, man. Using Awk is its own punishment... ;-)

Comment: Thanks @ByteCommander